# Define same environment with different amount of parameters

Tags: environments

I want to define two versions of the environment \begin{mainbox} \end{mainbox}, depending if I provide zero or one parameter. I want to use them like this:

```
\begin{mainbox}
    stuff
\end{mainbox}
\begin{mainbox}{title}
    stuff
\end{mainbox}
```

The definition of the mainboxes looks like this:+

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\newenvironment{mainbox}[1]{
    \thmbox[M]{\textbf{#1}}
    \hspace*{-1.9em}\slshape\ignorespaces
    \normalfont
}
{
    \endthmbox\vspace*{.75ex}
}
\newenvironment{mainbox*}{
    \thmbox[M]{$\ $\hspace{33.75pt}$\ $}
    \hspace*{-1.9em}\slshape\ignorespaces
    \normalfont
}
{
    \endthmbox\vspace*{.75ex}
}
```

In both cases I want to create a box. The one with no parameter has no title, the one with the parameter has a title. One fix is to give them differen names, like mainbox and mainbox*, but I tought there must be a more elegant way. Can someone help me?

Comment: Why don't you use simply an optional argument?

Comment: Because I have no Idea how to use them in this context.

Comment: Something like `\newenvironment{mainbox}[1][]` and then `\begin{mainbox}` or `\begin{mainbox}[title]`

Comment: Because I have a bigger Template behind this command I can't use "[ ]-Arguments". I need to use "{ }-Arguments".

Comment: Then you give `{}` when there is no extra option. It is not really a good idea to have interfaces with an optional argument in `{}` (it sort of can be done, but one shouldn't). I is not hard to check if the `{}` argument is empty and then react on that.

Comment: Hmmm... You're right, I think I have to rewrite a lot of code... Can you give me a detailed answer for the optional argument solution?

Comment: It might be an idea to use @name to tag the person you are answering, then they will be notified that your comment was directed at them.

Comment: @daleif you are right. Can someone provide me a detailed solution with optional arguments for my problem? I tried it myself, but I failed

Comment: you can use `\ifblank{#1}{code id blank}{code id not blank}`, and add that to your definition (`\ifblank` comeds from `etoolbox` and  use the env definition campa gave above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I was a bit stupid. It was pretty easy. Here is the solution. Thank you guys in the comments for the ideas!

```
\newenvironment{mainbox}[1][]{
        \thmbox[M]{\ifblank{#1}{$\ $\hspace{33.75pt}$\ $}{\textbf{#1}}}
        \hspace*{-1.9em}\slshape\ignorespaces
        \normalfont
    }
    {
        \endthmbox\vspace*{.75ex}
    }
```

Comment: You should accept this answer if it worked for you.